# Unable to deploy my existing application on OpenShift

Tags: openshift

When I tried to deploy my existing Spring MVC application, hosted in BitBucket, which is running without any problem in my local server, I got the following error

```
Preparing build for deployment
Deployment id is 81e8de9f
Activating deployment
Starting jbossews cartridge
jbossews process failed to start
-------------------------
Git Post-Receive Result: failure
Activation status: failure
Activation failed for the following gears:
594409312d527130f700003e (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/594409312d527130f700003e/jbossews#<IO:0x00000001418290>#<IO:0x00000001418218)
Deployment completed with status: failure
postreceive failed
```

and the build was successful (from their log).

Comment: what's the oupt of `oc debug dc/YOUR-DC` in the shell `control start`